# Why is the spherical cosine defined this way?

Tags: spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

I'm reading Stahl's: *Geometry from Euclid to Knots*. In the first part of the text, he argues that

$$\cos (A )=\frac{\cos (a)-\cos(b)\cos(c)}{\sin(b)\sin(c)}$$

and $\alpha$ an spherical angle. But by taking the $\cos \theta= \cfrac{a}{h}$ from plane geometry, and looking at:

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

My first guess would be to define the spherical cosine as $\cos(A)=\cfrac{b}{a}$ or $\cos(A)=\cfrac{c}{a}$ or perhaps they are defined this way in disguise and the formula for the spherical cosine actually is the suggestion I made? I guess that the definition for spherical cosine should mimic the definition for the plane cosine in some sense, but I don't see what exactly it is *mimicking* in this case.

Also, Stahl says that this is the cosine laws, not exactly the cosine. I looked at another pages: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry), [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalTrigonometry.html). And it seems that people derive the cosine laws and then, the cosine appears as a consequence. I guess in plane geometry it is the other way around but I'm not certain, at least all books I took were this way.

I have found [the following here](https://archive.org/stream/planeandspherica031803mbp#page/n293/mode/2up):

> [image]

Which lines up with what I have written above but given what I wrote for $\sin$ at least, $\cos$ is still a little bit weird. But for $\sin$, I would expect to have $\sin(B)=\cfrac{b}{c}$, but I have $\sin(B)=\cfrac{\sin b}{\sin c}$ instead. Why the second instead of the first? Is it just an arbitrary decision? Is it better to do this way?

Comment: not a definition. A theorem. The sine and cosine are the familiar ones. The sphere has radius one.

Comment: @WillJagy I'm confused: Isn't the familiar ones the ones I mentioned?

Comment: You should check the following link. Also note that the standard law of cosine should be obtained as a limiting case of the spherical cosine law. Enjoy!


  [1]: http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic246919.files/March-07.pdf

Comment: For future visitors, I highly recommend [Spherical Trigonometry](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/19770) written by I. Todhunter.  Chapter IV, (page 17) onwards, including Article 37-40 provide a proof for the spherical law of cosines.  Again, the law is not a definition, but a theorem that relates the sides (nomalized by the radius) to each interior spherical angle of a spherical triangle.